# Can AnyBody help me to convert thr RestSharp C# to Httprequest Method?

Tags: c#

```
  var client = new RestClient("enter code here");
  client.Timeout = -1;
  var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
  request.AddHeader("company", "009");
  request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Basic kkkksdafasdfas=");
  request.AddParameter("name", "fsdfsd");
  request.AddParameter("age", "20");
  request.AddParameter("category", "002");
  request.AddParameter("illness", "001");
  request.AddParameter("priority", "2");
  request.AddParameter("primaryDiagnosis", "K02.9");
  request.AddParameter("medicalRecordNo", "000249814Q");
  request.AddParameter("serviceType", "O");
  request.AddParameter("admissionType", "M");
  request.AddParameter("visitDate", "16/01/2022");
  request.AddParameter("doctorLicenseNo", "22");
  request.AddParameter("currency", "QAR");
  request.AddParameter("mobileNo", "55936929");
  request.AddParameter("illnessDetails", "tooth ache");
  request.AddParameter("treatmentsData", "[{\"treatType\":\"O\",\"treatCode\":\"2222\",\"quantity\":\"1.00\",\"treatDesc\":\"BREAKAGE CHARGES FOR FIXED RETAINERS\",\"dosage\":\"010\",\"durationUnit\":\"D\",\"duration\":\"1\",\"estimatedAmount\":\"325.00\",\"remarks\":\"test\"}]");
  request.AddFile("document", "/C:/Users/a/Desktop/kqic.png");
  request.AddParameter("diagnosisData", "[{\"diagCode\":\"22\"}]");
  request.AddParameter("admissionPeriod", "1");
  IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
  Console.WriteLine(response.Content);
```

---

```
 **Code Tried**
  string url = "`enter code here`";
  var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
  request.Method = "POST";
  request.Headers["Authorization"] = "Basic YWxzaGVmYV9=";
  request.Headers["Company"] = "00";
  var parameters = new NameValueCollection();
  parameters.Add("name", "dsfds");
  parameters.Add("age", "22");
  parameters.Add("category", "002");
  using(var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream()))
  { 
      streamWriter.Write(parameters); 
  }
  var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
  using (var streamReader = new  StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
  { 
  var result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();    
  }
```

The above is the code I've tried. Can anyone help me to convert from restSharp to httprequest? I need those parameters to be passed in the httprequest post method. But when I tried this, it says `URL Rejected`. Can any one help me out?

Comment: Can you provide the code of what you tried so far ?

Comment: @QuentinRoger  sure... i will edit the question with my code

Comment: Code which i treied

Comment: Is this in your code? string url = "`enter code here`";
`enter code here` seems to be no url so "URL Rejected" makes sense to me.